# Creating a configuration file in a Java application including security

Tags: java, security

I have to create a java application wich makes a connection to a DB.
Everything is easy until this point. But I need to include a **configuration option** with the porpouse of allow the end user enter their own parameters (server host, user, pass, database, port, etc.) in order to connect to the DB. Another easy task. Now every time the user starts the application I need to read these presets given by the end user, in other way remember the user's connection preferences.

I found an easy way to do this using the Properties library in the Java's API. But I have a security issue. The user's preferences are exposed to be access easily (username and password mainly).

Is there a way to save this parameters encrypted?

I need a good and simpliest solution for this security issue.

Comment: You may consider using a simple XOR encryption algorithm (but the users need to have an additional password/key for your application). The solution you'll adopt depends greatly on the level of security you need to provide. PGP-encryption is a quite good option. However, keep in mind that in many cases such files are even un-encrypted (e.g. private settings-files in Maven); but in such a case, users have to keep these files private and protected.

Comment: I considered the password/key option too but results in a complicate task to the end user. Someone suggested me trying to write the user's preferences into the win reg but I don't have any idea in how to do this.

Comment: If it is not possible or easy encrypt the data I want at least hide that data the best possible

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. In FileZilla Client 3.6.0.2, I found my login data easily without encrypted. If it was possible to save this parameters encrypted, FileZilla would do it.

[image: my login data is exposed to be access]

Comment: Thanks, I know that any experienced user can access to that information easily. I only want to try to hide the data better.

Comment: @UncleSam Bad encryption is worse than no encryption, because users will mistakenly think that their data is safe, hence cause a greater security leak.

Comment: Any solution to encrypting and hidding data in my Java application?